# 22' shallow Well with 4.8 gallon Preasure Tank

Tags: water

My pump takes 2 minutes and 46 seconds to fill my 4.8 gallon Pressure Tank.  If I was to add
A 20 gallon Tank, would it take 4 times as long to fill? There are no leaks, water pressure holds for weeks if not use and longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you **add** it, so you have both tanks in use, about 5 times as long to fill, **and** 5 times as long to empty.

If you **replace** it, about 4 times.

That's assuming you are measuring fill time while no water is being used. If water is being used during the fill you are measuring, the measurment is not really of "time to fill the tank" it's "time to fill the tank while supplying water to something else as well."

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer.  So, what you think?  My $165.00 Pump isn't as good as maybe A $600.00 dollar one would be?  Over 10 minutes to fill that sounds like A long time.  My 17' well will fill the same size tank in 30 seconds.  This is the second shallow well pump I have and on the 22' well.  It is A little better than the first one I had on it, but stills needs some improvement I guess.

Comment: If you have **a different question, ask it as a new question.** IME it's not how much you paid for the pump, it's what the specifications are (if the pump is the limiting factor) or issues with the pipe/foot valve/intake screen (if the well plumbing is the limiting factor) To the extent that a lower cost pump may not be as capable as a higher cost pump, sure, that might affect things. So does the static water level in the respective wells, particularly for shallow well (surface-mounted) pumps. a difference of 5 or 10 feet in the suction head is a big deal; that maxes out at 25-27 feet.

Comment: If the water supply is adequate for your use, the fill time does not matter (past the recommendation that it should be at least a minute so as not to have too many pump starts - more tank and fewer starts is better.) If the water supply is not adequate, that's a different question. Could be the pump, the plumbing, or the well itself (if the recharge rate is insufficient, the static water level will drop (to a dynamic water level) until the pump can't pump, or can't pump faster than the water comes in. Sometimes the solution to that is a slow pump to a very large storage tank.)

Comment: Gotta agree with @Ecnerwal, the pump may be sized to the production capacity of the well. Each well has it's own characteristics.  One well might only be able to produce 3 gpm and an other maybe 30 gpm.  The best practice would be to have an experienced well person do a "draw down" test to see what your well can actually produce. Also consider a submersible pump... like Encerwal said, a surface mounted pump really loses a lot of efficiency if the water level in the well drops a lot.